# ColdFusion alternative to cURL

Tags: php, cookies, curl, coldfusion, cfhttp

I'm trying to re-create a PHP function in ColdFusion (as I don't know PHP) and think most of my function is not too bad but having issues when dealing with the cURL function in PHP.

The function code is

```
$cookie_string = $this->EASW_KEY."; ".$this->EASF_SESS ."; ".$this->PHISHKEY;
$ch = curl_init($search);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'x-http-method-override: GET',
    $this->XSID)
);

//Contains the JSON file returned
$EAPSEARCH = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

unset (List of variables);
```

I'm assuming the CFHTTP function is my best ally but not really sure how to deal with the re-code. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're right, CFHTTP is the way to go. Here's a version of your call above translated to a CFHTTP call:

```
<cfhttp url="http://some.server/path" method="POST" result="resultName>
  <cfhttpparam type="cookie" name="EASW_KEY" value="#EASW_VALUE#" />
  <cfhttpparam type="cookie" name="EASF_SESS" value="#EASF_SESS_VALUE#" />

  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="x-http-method-override" value="GET" />

  <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#myJSONStringVariable#" />
</cfhttp>

<cfdump var="#resultName# />
```

The cfhttp tag is documented here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_g-h_09.html

Comment: Little tip and tidbit, if you are receiving JSON from your cfhttp call, you will want to use #resultName.fileContent.toString("utf-8")#. Also, if you will be providing the JSON returned to the front end, you will want to ensure that you set the content appropriately -- with both a type and charset <cfcontent type="application/json; charset=UTF-8" reset="false">

Comment: Thanks that worked. Just need to work on how to get the authentication passed in and working now!

Comment: cfhttp supports a username and password attribute for http basic authentication, so you may be ok in that regard. If you're trying to use other schemes it'll be considerably harder I believe.

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but the above example is the reason I love Coldfusion. It is SO much cleaner looking than PHP.

Comment: @rob M: it looks cleaner because curl covers the following protocol apart from http and https: http, https, ftp, gopher, telnet, dict, file, and ldap protocols. libcurl also supports HTTPS certificates, HTTP POST, HTTP PUT, FTP. This is the equivalent of using cfftp, cfldap, cfmail, cfpop, cfile and etc.